# Antenna ground and digital ground

Tags: rf, pcb-design, noise

I know that there are many similar topics here, but none of them answers my questions.
I have an 868MHz RF module (cc1120 + cc1190), the output power is around 27dBm. The module is with a castellated connector.
The module is mounted on a 4-layer PCB. 1) - signal + gnd, 2) - gnd, 3) - power supply, 4) - signal + gnd.
Connect the ground of the SMA connector to the digital ground on the PCB? 
Both grounds are connected in the module. Is it better to separate the RF ground from the digital one as in the picture? Place the antenna ground on all 4 layers and connect them via Via?
Should the analog part be put on the bottom?
In the first version, I underestimated the signal strength and in the analog part of the PCB a demodulated signal from the RF module appeared on the differential amplifiers.

[image: TOP]
[image: BOT]

Answer (score 2):

From my knowledge, ground splits are detrimental in 90% of cases. One reason could be that our brain's EM simulator can never be quite perfect. That often leads to GND cuts where they cause havoc. So I always sway on the conservative side and make my grounds as solid as possible. In your case keeping ground currents from AGND by splits probably makes sense, considering your first iteration experience. But keep in mind that signals should not cross any of these splits.

What I would stay away from is splitting the antenna ground from DGND. Keep in mind that RF always works relative to a ground mass. When you reduce it, you reduce the transmitted efficiency. This counts especially in the vicinity of the antenna.

Anyway, is this an off the shelf module? If so, don't they mention the correct usage in the datasheet?